# newline handling inside chunk/phrase

Tags: java, itext

I'm a bit confused about newline handling in chunks text. The following code

```
  Paragraph para = new Paragraph();
  para.add(new Chunk("  A"));
  para.add(new Chunk("\n  B"));
  para.add(new Chunk("\n  C"));
  document.add(para);
```

add a paragraph of 3 lines, where the first line in the resulting pdf document is slightly shifted to the right, while I was expecting that the lines began at the same exact horizontal position. Note that every letter "A", "B", "C" is preceded by two space char.

If I use a newline also in the first Chunk, the three lines are perfectly horizontally aligned in the output document:

```
  Paragraph para = new Paragraph();
  para.add(new Chunk("\n  A"));
  para.add(new Chunk("\n  B"));
  para.add(new Chunk("\n  C"));
  document.add(para);
```

So the question is: why the presence of a newline character on a chunk text affect the horizontal position of the text itself?

The version of iText I'm using is **5.2.1** .

Comment: For reference, anyone else investigating this issue can refer to this: http://itext.2136553.n4.nabble.com/newline-handling-inside-chunk-phrase-td4655550.html. It's a bug in some versions of iText.

Comment: Actually...does anyone know where the official bug for this is listed? or what version of iText this was fixed in?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>By default, iText sets an indentation for the first line of each `Paragraph`. What you want is to set this indentation space to 0. See the API for [Paragraph.setFirstLineIndent(float)](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Paragraph.html#setFirstLineIndent%28float%29).</strike>

Comment: doesn't work. Moreover, looking at the source code of Paragraph class, it seems that the default value of firstLineIndent is 0.

Comment: You are right, I made a wrong assumption. Looks like a bug, or at least an odd and undocumented behavior.