# Preety - print json and convert in to pdf

Tags: java

Problem statement: preetify string in to json format and store in pdf file.
Earlier I am able to solve this problem by preetifying string using below code.

```
public Long convertJsonToPdf(Long customerId,
                                 Object json,
                                 String documentType) {
    log.info("In convert Json To Pdf");
    String fileName = documentType + ".pdf";
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String json1 = null;
    try {
        json1 = objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(json);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        log.warn("Error occurred in parsing json {}", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    try {
        com.itextpdf.text.Document document = new com.itextpdf.text.Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filename));
        document.open();
        document.add(new Paragraph(json1));
        Paragraph signature = new Paragraph("Created by me.");
        signature.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_RIGHT);
        document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
        document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
        document.add(signature);
        document.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.info("exception occurred in creating pdf {}", e.getMessage(), e);
    }  
    // code to store in cloud.
}
```

Above code was able to solve my problem. Now it is not able to solve my problem i.e not able preetify the json.

I tried other solutions from this [preety-print-json-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105795/pretty-print-json-in-java).
I tried using JSONObject.

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString); // Convert text to object
System.out.println(json.toString(4)); // Print it with specified indentation
```

or this:

```
json1 = objectMapper.readTree(json.toString()).toPrettyString();
```

When I print json1 in my console it is able to preetify it properly. but when this is stored in pdf then at a position there is a gap to 3-4 line between two field. This error occur for a specific file. In other file it is able to print correctly in pdf.

json in pdf file:

```
"city": "city name",  





"state": "state name"
```

Comment: *"Above code was able to solve my problem. Now it is not able to solve my problem i.e not able preetify the json."* -  What?  It worked before but it doesn't work now?  You must have changed something.

Comment: No I didn't change anything.

Comment: So how come it stopped working?  Software doesn't stop working unless something has been changed.

Comment: Currently, I don't know the reason that why it stopped. Need to dig deeper in to it.

Comment: I suspect that the problem maybe due to inconsistent handling of newline characters in a Paragraph.  Try breaking the string into lines, and adding them as chunks with a Chunk.NEWLINE between each.  There are apparently bugs in some versions of iText.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10409766 and http://itext.2136553.n4.nabble.com/newline-handling-inside-chunk-phrase-td4655550.html

Comment: And if this is the root cause then my guess is that the change (see above) is that you used a different version of iText.

Comment: (But I really don't see the value in turning JSON into a PDF.  JSON is more useful as plain text ... unless you are in the deforestation business!)